# checkers game board: store object refs or char values?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, object, immutability

just a general question. I have a checkers game with alphabeta-search aigame that works pretty well overall. I wonder if it is advisable to store object references in the board array and have a nice clean code, or to better use a char-value array and use switch() statements to branch for the different pieces. I guess it depends on how memory (in)efficient an object array and the cloning of it is...

I store the game position in a board[][] array that references game piece objects that implement all the characteristics of a piece, in particular the routine to find possible moves.

My main getmoves loop looks somehting like this:

```
for(sq:Squares) {
    allmoves.addAll(sq.getPossiblemoves());
}
```

Each square is an object from a class hierarchy like:

```
interface GamePiece {...}
class EmptySquare implements GamePiece {...}
class Pawn extends EmptySquare implements GamePiece {...}
class Queen extends EmptySquare implements GamePiece {...}
```

The AI looks for a best move in an alpha-beta-tree recursion that clones the game board for each recursion, like:

```
int alphabeta(Board b....) {
    for(mv:b.possibleMoves) {
      score = -alphabeta(b.doMove(mv),...)
    }
}
```

where doMove returns a brand new Board object with a new board-array with cloned game pieces, so I have to do a lot of object creation. It works well and the code is pretty clean. I'm just not sure if this is a good approach in terms of performance. A typical search for a best move involves around 50000-500000 nodes, which equals a complete copy of the game board and all referenced game piece objects for about half of those nodes (all the leafs are just evaluated and don't need further cloning of the board). It uses around 800MB of RAM.

I could also use a board[][] array that stores chars or try an even tighter way to store all game pieces... any experience on how much of a difference this would make? Is it worth sacrificing the nicer code with the polymorph call to getPossibleMoves()? If I store char values, I would have to branch based on the game piece and call different subroutines to get the possible moves. I thought that this would be a bad approach in therms of OOP principles, but I suspect that my approach is bad in terms of performance principles. Just how bad, I don't know...

Comment: How come you ask about checkers, and the offer "Queen" and "Pawn" as examples?

Comment: @Ira: because that's what we call them in Austria... the game in German is actually called "Queen" ("Dame"). Not sure how other countries call them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you haven't considered using "bit boards", e.g., a 64 bit integer where a bit N tells you that a piece is on a square N.  With checkers, you need two bit boards, one for black, one for red.

Move generation can probably be done in terms of bit operations.  If not, you can still easily enumerate the board positions 0..63, check the piece type, etc; it won't change the essential logic of the rest of your code.

But now you can also store huge transposition tables cheaply.  And that will make endgame play really good.

You may want to start with abstract operations for accessing information.  For your game to play well, you'll want to tune it to allow deeper searches.   In this case, you may find that clean abstraction is inconsistent with high performance.   I suggest you get it right first, and then replace abstract functions with their realization when you want to tune the code.

Comment: in fact I did consider bitwise storage of some sort... but since this is my "Lets learn Java" project, I was busy getting the logic right... it plays pretty well now (I have lost every single game but one) but of course could be much better and faster. If I do it the way you suggest, it would mean a more or less complete rewrite... not sure if its worth it really, but I'll consider!